# TiMidity: need help compiling this library for the iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm using a powerful library called TiMidity, which I'm sure many iPhone developers have used already used. This is a platform-independent set of programs, but during compile-time in XCode (gcc compiler), there are hundreds of dependency errors that come up.

If anyone here has used TiMidity before for their apps, your advice will be gold.

Thanks everyone, 
Phil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use [this script](http://pseudogreen.org/bzr/sandbox/iphone/build_for_iphoneos) to compile static libraries for the iPhone, but TiMidity++ isn't a library and the API's it uses to output sound on OS X aren't available on the iPhone OS.

Here's what I've gotten so far:

1. Save `build_for_iphoneos` somewhere in your path and `+x` it
2. `cd` to the extractd TiMidity++ folder
3. `build_for_iphoneos simulator`
   This will fail
4. Copy `timidity/newton_tables.c` somewhere safe.
5. `make clean`
6. `build_for_iphoneos device`
7. Manually edit `timidity/makefile` and remove all references to `DAU_DARWIN` and `darwin_a`
8. Copy `newton_tables.c` back into the `timidity` subfolder and `touch` it
9. `make`

You should now have a `timidity` binary that can be used from the shell on a jailbroken device (after signed via ldid of course) and object files you can include in your project.

Note: TiMidity++ is GPL, so you will have to release your application under that license if you use any part of it. Also, this is really messy because TiMidity++ wasn't designed to be used this way, all of the darwin integration is broken on iPhone OS, and automake confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove AU_DARWIN from ./Makefile as well as timidity/Makefile.