# What techniques are available for programatically transforming HTML/DOM in an iOS Application?

Tags: html, ios, dom, transformation

I'm processing a variety of RSS feeds, which contain summaries, as well as the target page URL content, and trying to use a uniform transformation method.

XSLT was the first thing that occurred to me to try, as it would accomplish what I want, in a standard way, without a lot of fuss aside from adding new XSLT stylesheets to accommodate uniquely formatted sites and feed content.

Problem: XSLT libraries are considered "private" in iOS, and even linking statically against your own copy will get you rejected by the Apple Store analysis tools.

I've looked into the possibility if injecting the stylesheet and data into a UIWebView that wasn't displayed, but this seems like a really roundabout and hackish way to get at the system's underlying XSLT processor in an "approved" fashion.

What alternative techniques/libraries exist which would let me do this in a standard fashion, ie: without rolling my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your requirements, but one possbility would be to use [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/tutorial/index.html) (which is allowed in iOS) to parse the XML and if necessary manipulate the DOM. If you really need to do XML transformations this is going to be more effort than XSLT, but if you just need to extract data from the XML, that can be done fairly easily with xpath queries.

That said, I have read several people claiming they got XSLT working on iOS and had their apps approved in the app store. In particular, I've seen [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4123575/2334192) claimed as a working solution by multiple people. And if that fails, [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6271752/2334192) suggested building the libxslt library yourself with renamed symbols to bypass the app store checks. I would only suggest that as a last resort though.

Comment: This was the closest to what I ended up doing.  Though I'd taken a look at these answers before, your answer prompted me to look again, and I was able to get libxslt working.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to look into Hpple for something powerful but light weight / native. See the tutorial on getting started here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to also recommend TFHpple but I'm also going to elaborate on the solution. I've explored an app that navigates a 3rd party (well, I'm the 3rd party, they're the source but that's semantics) website/data source but there are some pitfalls. The biggest pitfall is obvious: if the data source DOM changes you need to change your app and re-release. A creative way around this would be to publish/expose a global copy of the DOM on a public server that way the end user doesn't have to update their app any time the data source changes (as long as the change isn't radical).

For instance, if your expected DOM search in TFHpple is `@"//figure[@class='figure']/a"` and then a week from now your data source's resource you're looking for is altered to `@"//figure1[@class='figure1']/a"` you just opened yourself to an App Store release... UNLESS... you publish the expected DOM searches on a web server you control in a data dictionary that your app can consume and serve out to the various DOM search elements within your app. The only problem I foresee here is that if the data source adds or removes a data element you want to consume you either have to release a build or handle the removal ahead of time (respectively).

Lastly if the data source DOM isn't well formed or consistent you may be beating your head against a wall more times than not.